# Better Practices: Eliminate the nested loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, underscore.js

I'm iterating through some objects like so (using Underscore.js):

```
      _.each(obj.Things, function(thing) {
        _.each(thing.SubThings, function(subThing) {
          _.each(subThing.SubSubThing, function(subSubThing) {
            things.push(subSubThing);
          });
        });
      });
```

I don't like how this looks, architecturally speaking. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish tasks like this?

Comment: It's not clear what that means; the outer two iterations ignore the parameter that's passed in, so what's going on?

Comment: Break the callbacks up and keep them all at the same level as named functions.  You're falling into callback hell.

Comment: @Pointy: Fixed that. Might make more sense now.

Comment: OK, well if you really need to traverse the entire three-dimensional data structure, you're going to end up doing more-or-less the exact same thing no matter how it's written. If you need to do this very frequently, then you'd probably be better off thinking of better ways to structure the data instead of making this operation faster.

Comment: @Pointy, OP is more interested in readability than in efficiency.

Comment: @IgweKalu perhaps; that's not what I interpreted "architecturally" to mean.

Comment: OP, mapping and reducing will do for the exact data structure you described. But @Pointy does have a good point, you'd be better of revising your data design...

Comment: There are many points to consider in architecture, efficiency, maintainability and readability are some of them. OP mentioned *looks*, which informed my thought on expressiveness.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it to make your code more readable is to unwind your nested calls and use just regular function calls.

```
_.each(obj.Things, processThing);

function processThing(thing) {
    _.each(thing.SubThings, processSubThing);
}

function processSubThing(subThing) {
    _.each(subThing.SubSubThing, processSubSubThing);
}

function processSubSubThin(subSubThing) {
    things.push(subSubThing);
}
```

if you use ES6/ES2015 you can use arrow function feature

```
let processThing = thing => _.each(thing.SubThings, processSubThing);

let processSubThing = subThing => _.each(subThing.SubSubThing, processSubSubThing);

let processSubSubThin = subSubThing => things.push(subSubThing);

_.each(obj.Things, processThing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is all objects Array?

Then, does this make sense?

```
var things = _.flatten(_.map(obj.Things, function(thing) {
    return _.pluck(thing.SubThings, "SubSubThings");
}));
```

If you don't want to create a new things.

```
things.push(_.map(obj.Things, function(thing) {
  return _.pluck(thing.SubThings, "SubSubThings");
}));
things = _.flatten(things);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce`, a sufficiently expressive solution exists:

```
var things = obj.Things.map(function (thing) {
    return thing.SubThings;
}).reduce(function (things, subthing) {
    return things.concat(subthing.SubSubThings);
}, []);
```